# Error in ordering variable names from the string expression using ast in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to parse this list of equations and divide it into two lists as seen in the code, the order in which they appear is important, however, once it has been parsed, the list var1 of variables is not in the correct order like in the equations, any suggerence?

```
eq_list2 = ["der_w_hSP - w_FW + 2*t_FW", "2*der_t_CP - R_CI + R_CO", "3*der_w_BSS - w_FW + 4*s_CI + 2*s_BRC + 3*t_BW + 2*t_CW"]

var2 = []
var1 = []
for i in range(len(eq_list2)):
    #print(eq_list[i])
    names2 = [
        node.id for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(eq_list2[i]))
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name)
    ]
    print(names2)
    for k in range(len(names2)):
        if names2[k].startswith('der_'):
            print('yes')
            var2.append(names2[k])
        else:
            print('false')
            var1.append(names2[k])

print(var2)
print(var1)
```

```
['der_w_hSP', 'der_t_CP', 'der_w_BSS']
['w_FW', 't_FW', 'R_CO', 'R_CI', 't_CW', 't_BW', 's_BRC', 'w_FW', 's_CI']
```

Comment: You only have 3 elements in `eq_list2 `. So what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: the output in var1, would have to follow the order of the variables as in the equations , the current output is var1 = ['w_FW', 't_FW', 'R_CO', 'R_CI', 't_CW', 't_BW', 's_BRC', 'w_FW', 's_CI'] and the correct result would be var1 = ["w_FW", "t_FW", "R_CI", "R_CO", "s_CI", "s_BRC", "t_BW", "t_CW"]

Answer (score 1):

`ast.walk` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk) as yielding a tree's nodes "**in no specified order**", and that's easy to verify by examining the code (which you'll find in the file `ast.py` in the Python library directory on your machine):

```py
def walk(node):
    """
    Recursively yield all descendant nodes in the tree starting at *node*
    (including *node* itself), in no specified order.  This is useful if you
    only want to modify nodes in place and don't care about the context.
    """
    from collections import deque
    todo = deque([node])
    while todo:
        node = todo.popleft()
        todo.extend(iter_child_nodes(node))
        yield node
```

The code uses a double-ended queue to store unvisited AST nodes in order to avoid recursion. In effect, that does a breadth-first traverse, which means that nodes closer to the root of the tree will be visited first. Since expressions are mostly left-associative, right-hand operators tend to be closer to the root of the parse tree, and thus come earlier in the visit order.

A simple way to visit nodes in depth-first left-to-right order is to use a recursive walker:

```py
def dfswalk(node):
    """
    Recursively yield all descendant nodes of an AST starting at *node*
    (including *node* itself) in depth-first order.
    """
    yield node
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        yield from dfswalk(child)
```

Using that function instead of `ast.walk` should produce variables in the order you expect, although I don't believe there is a guarantee that `iter_child_nodes` iterates every node type in left-to-right textual order, so you will need to test it for the various syntaxes which interest you.

If you anticipate having to handle very complicated expressions, you could use your own stack rather than recursion.